# Search by keyword mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a table based of a keyword.  My table looks like:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tweetBody  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| datePosted | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| likes      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dislikes   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the query I am trying to do looks like

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE tweetBody LIKE'is';
```

I am trying to find all tweets that contain the work 'is' however I am getting no results returned.  When clearly I do have tweets that contain is.  Here is my current table:

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+
| id | username | tweetBody                                                                                                      | datePosted | likes | dislikes |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+
|  1 | ryan4664 | This is a tweeeeeeet!                                                                                          | 2015/08/09 |     0 |        0 |
|  2 | ryan4664 | Swag chillwave skateboard, roof party messenger bag jean shorts keytar gastropub DIY. Lomo shabby chic liter   | 2015/08/10 |     0 |        0 |
|  3 | ryan4664 | z YOLO slow-carb. Paleo Brooklyn pop-up whatever, hoodie tilde Odd Future semiotics tote b                     | 2015/08/10 |     0 |        0 |
|  4 | ryan4664 | ter distillery church-key meditation chillwave authentic polaroid direct trade. Aesthetic fixie Wes Anderson 9 | 2015/08/10 |     0 |        0 |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: use sql wildcards: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a wildcard to your [`like`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) search

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE tweetBody LIKE '%is%';
```

> % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>   _ matches exactly one character.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!